# How to join 2 tables from different databases with not equals

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i want to join 2 tables from different databases.

for example i have `table1` and `table2`.

on result I want to take `table2` datas, which are not exist on `table1`.

`table1`

```
name     langid
name1    en
name1    no
name2    en
name3    en
```

`table2`

```
name     langid
name1    en
name1    id
name1    no
name2    en
```

so the result should be like this

result what i want

```
name     langid
name1    en
name1    no
name1    id
name2    en
name3    en
```

code that i try

```
select p66.language_string_text_id, p66.language_string, p66.language_id
FROM project66.languagestrings p66
JOIN wisehouse.languagestrings wh 
ON p66.language_string_text_id != wh.language_string_text_id
GROUP BY p66.language_string_text_id, p66.language_id
```

but this code is not working.

Comment: 'I want to take table2 datas, which are not exist on table1.' - how come name1/en is in your desired result then?

Comment: the two db are on the same mysql /maria db server

Comment: @P.Salmon from `table1` basically i show all `table1` data and i want to marge with `table2` but, on `table2` i dont want to show that already have on `table1`.

Comment: @scaisEdge yup..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `UNION` which will remove duplicates and not a join:

```
select name, langid from table1
union
select name, langid from table2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kRSYgZnyiBKzd3cY4RBwFA/0).
Results:

```
| name  | langid |
| ----- | ------ |
| name1 | en     |
| name1 | no     |
| name1 | id     |
| name2 | en     |
| name3 | en     |
```

Comment: No. Check the demo.

Comment: can i export result of union, i try export but its show me ull insert record..
btw, im on local using phpmyadmin and mariadb

Comment: I can't tell how to use the results you get. The code is a simple query.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like below

```
select p66.language_string_text_id, p66.language_string, p66.language_id
FROM project66.languagestrings p66 
WHERE p66.language_string_text_id NOT IN 
(SELECT wh.language_string_text_id FROM wisehouse.languagestrings wh) 
GROUP BY p66.language_string_text_id, p66.language_id
```

Answer (score 0):

if the two db are on the same db server  you coukd try using aleft join where don't match

assuming   project66.languagestrings  is the table2 (the one that not match ) and  wisehouse.languagestrings the table1

```
  select p66.language_string_text_id, p66.language_string, p66.language_id 
  FROM project66.languagestrings p66
  LEFT JOIN wisehouse.languagestrings wh  ON p66.language_string_text_id = wh.language_string_text_id
      and p66.language_id = wh.language_id
  WHERE wh.language_string_text_id is null
```

Comment: update your question add  the query you  are really using  ..  the actual result and the expected  result  ..NB in your sample you are extracting also value present  in  both table (in mine shoulld not)  and this is in contrast with your declaration " I want to take table2 datas, which are not exist on table1." ....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `DB1`.`table`.`id` , `DB1`.`table`.`name` 
FROM `DB1`.`table` 
JOIN `DB2`.`table2` ON `DB1`.`table`.`id` = `DB2`.`table2`.`parent`
```